# impossible to install Framework 3.5

Tags: .net-3.5, .net-framework

few days ago I formatted one of my computers (XP Home SP2 with prior updates installed). Now I am trying to install NET Framework 3.5, but  display this error:

**[03/21/10,17:19:36] Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0a: [2] Error: Installation failed for component Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0a. MSI returned error code 1603
[03/21/10,17:20:17] WapUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0a is not installed.**

Already i have tried this to try solve this issue, but the problem persists.

1.- unistall all frameworks and reinstall from scratch

2.- clean all temps file and reinstall from scratch

3.- unistall and clean all frameworks with **dotnetfx cleanup tool** and reinstall from scratch

4.- install .NET Framework 3.5 full package

But all these possibles solutions have failed.

Any idea to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not programming related. Try superuser instead

Comment: same problem here but with 3.5.1 in Windows 7 x64 professional